# How can you disable shapes from being selected?

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2016

How can you disable shapes from being selected?

If I do a CTRL + A, is there anyway to set a shape so that it is excluded from the selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Layers. Create multiple layers. Ensure all objects are assigned to at least one layer. Visit Layer Properties and Lock the layers you want to exclude from selection.